# How to disable wheel_zoom in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

Usually I do plotting inside of IPython Notebook with pylab mode.

Whenever I use Bokeh, I like to enable `output_notebook()` to show my plot inside of the IPython notebook.

Most annoying part is that Bokeh enable `wheel_zoom` by default which cause unintended zoom in IPython notebook.

I know I can avoid this by passing comma separated `tools` string what I want to include into `bokeh.plotting.figure`. but with this solution, I should list up the other tools but `wheel_zoom`.

Is there any way to exclude `wheel_zoom` only? or Can I disable `wheel_zoom` in global setting or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open PR to improve this, it will be in the the `0.11` release.